# Shared Collection Between Client and Server Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor, client

Beginner at Meteor. Just learning how everything works so bear with me.

Everything was working fine in one file, but after installing `iron:router` to have a multi-page application, I realized that it's better to have separate client and server files. Unfortunately, now I'm having trouble syncing the collection between the server and the client. I've read tons of tutorials, but nothing is working.

In my `server.js` file:

```
Streams = new Meteor.Collection("streams"); 
 if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('streams', function () {
  return Streams.find();
 });
}
```

In my `client.js` file:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
   Meteor.subscribe("streams");
   Template.body.helpers = function(){
     return Streams.find();
 }
}
```

After debugging, it says that "Streams" is not defined in the client. What's going on? How do I connect the collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic architecture :

`lib/streams.js`

```
Streams = new Meteor.Collection("streams");
```

`server/streams.js`

```
Meteor.publish("streams", function () {
  return Streams.find();
});
```

`client/streams.js`

```
Meteor.subscribe("streams");

Template.body.helpers({
  streams: function(){
    return Streams.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the `lib` folder supposed to be?

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation to understand the load and placement of files: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Comment: Create it at the root of your Meteor application, files under `lib` are always loaded first.

Comment: That works fine, but it's still not returning the collection... It should be updating in my client with `Streams.find()` but nothing's showing up...

Comment: The docs also note that the files in the `lib` folder are loaded first and are available to both client and server. It also suggests that collections related code go there. The Discover Meteor example app on github is a good place to see a well structured Meteor app with source, you'll see in the `lib` folder a collections folder where the collections declaration and CRUD are located:  https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/tree/master/lib

Comment: Is there a way to print the Streams collection in JSON to see if that's it's getting the correct data?

Comment: Post the rest of your code please. Inside the template helper, use `console.log(Streams.find().fetch());` to debug.

Comment: the result of the `console.log(Streams.find().fetch());` is `[]` but when I check the collection after running `meteor mongo`, it shows that it isn't empty...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `Streams` on the client as well.

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
   Streams = new Meteor.Collection("streams"); 
   Meteor.subscribe("streams");
   Template.body.helpers = function(){
     return Streams.find();
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess that takes away the error, but the `Streams.find()` part isn't returning anything and it's not an empty collection...

Answer (score 0):

If you use autopublish package, which is by default. You just need to do

> lib/streams.js
>
> Streams = new Meteor.Collection("streams");

part.