# Meteor.JS: Subscribe no working

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Im trying to subscribe my client side to my userFriends collection and Chrome's console display: `userFriends is not defined`

This is my code:

**Server side...**

```
userFriends = new Mongo.Collection("friends");
console.log(userFriends.find().fetch())
Meteor.publish("friends", function () {
    return userFriends.find();
});
```

**NOTE:** The console.log display in the terminal an empty array which is good

**Client side...**

```
Meteor.subscribe("friends");
console.log(userFriends.find().fetch())
```

**NOTE:** This is where Chrome's console display the error

what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

**UPDATE 1**: Now I can see the Friends collection in Chrome's console, but i cant insert data. I have the subscribe in client.js inside my client folder and my insert code is in friend.js inside client folder aswell.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443288/shared-collection-between-client-and-server-meteor/30443474

You need to declare the collection in shared code to make it available on both environments (create a top-level `lib` directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two correct answers but they do assume some knowledge for you. Here's what it looks like using Meteor's file structure (available at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

**In your /lib (shared) directory**

Make a file called "collections.js" and in it create your collection.

> userFriends = new Mongo.Collection("friends");

*I would instead do userFriends = new Mongo.Collection("userfriends"); so that your are always using the same word for your collection and you change the capitalization depending on if you're working on client or server. This is very helpful.*

**In Your /client directory**

Make a file called "subscriptions.js" and in it subscribe to your collection.

> Meteor.subscribe('friends');

**In Your /server directory**

Make a file called "publications.js" and in it publish your collection.

> Meteor.publish('friends',function(){
>     return userFriends.find();
>   });

You don't need a fetch or anything there.

Essentially your code is failing because of where you're trying to house everything. What I've given you is three points of where you work. Client, Shared, Server. Set your app up that way and it will be easy to immediately figure out where you're working.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey friend, thanks you for your help. Now i can access friend collection in chrome's console but I cant execute the insert in my code, I still get the access denied

Comment: Do you have autopublish and insecure removed? Try "meteor add insecure" and "meteor add autopublish." But really, that seems like a second question. Maybe make a new post specific to inserting or updating meteor collections.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy Hey, can you help me a with the same problem. My collections are declared in /lib as `Educations = new Mongo.Collection("educations");` and Published as `Meteor.publish("educations", function() { return Educations.find(); });` and  Subscribed with `Meteor.subscribe('educations')`. They show up in debug mode but not production mode. I get empty arrays in Browser console. Any idea why??

Comment: In your debug you may be using a different db. That's really all I can guess because if it's an empty array, there's no errors, there's just no data (usually).

Answer (score 3):

The collection needs to be defined on **both** the client and the server. Typically this is done by placing the definition in a shared directory like `lib`:

**lib/collections/user-friends.js**

```js
userFriends = new Mongo.Collection('friends');
```

Note the convention is to name the collection with the capitalized camel case version of the collection name. So calling it `Friends` would be more typical.

Comment: Thank you brother. Saved me a lot of time . I was going in circles.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the collection on both environments using shared code.

`lib/user-friends.js`

```
userFriends = new Mongo.Collection("friends");
```

`client/user-friends.js`

```
Meteor.subscribe("friends", function(){
  console.log(userFriends.find().fetch());
});
```

In the client, be aware that collection subscriptions are asynchronous by nature (there's network latency on the client, inherent to fetching the documents from the server).

This is why if you `console.log` your collection content right after `Meteor.subscribe`ing you'll get `[]`, but if you wait until the subscription is ready using a callback, documents will be displayed correctly.