# Meteor Collection Says It's Empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections, database

I posted this ([Shared Collection Between Client and Server Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443288/shared-collection-between-client-and-server-meteor)) earlier, and I'm not sure it's completely solved but I believe another problem has arisen.

When doing `console.log(Streams.find().fetch());` in my `client.js` file, the result is `[]`. But when I use `meteor mongo` to check the database (`db.Streams.find().forEach(printjson)`), three different objects show up.

What's going on?

In `lib/streams.js`:

`Streams = new Meteor.Collection("streams");`

In `server/server.js`:

```
Meteor.publish("streams", function () {
  return Streams.find();
});
```

In `client/client.js`:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Meteor.subscribe("streams");
    Template.body.helpers ({
      streams: function() {
        console.log(Streams.find().fetch());
        return Streams.find();
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: You really need to post your exact code here because we can't help you if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @saimeunt Added full code. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So according to Michael Mason and because you accepted his answer, in the end, it was just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess based on the linked question ([Shared Collection Between Client and Server Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443288/shared-collection-between-client-and-server-meteor)). In that question you are referring to the collection as `streams`:

`Streams = new Meteor.Collection("streams");`

But in this question you are using `Streams`:

`db.Streams.find().forEach(printjson) // Note the capital S in Streams`

So I would say it's probably a case-sensitivity thing, try:

`Streams = new Mongo.Collection("Streams");`

This will match the name of the mongo collection correctly. Also change `Meteor.Collection` to `Mongo.Collection` which is more up to date.

Comment: Nice catch, didn't thought about this.